# React Component is Not Displaying the Flash Message on First Submit

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the component below for user registration. I know that it is working at the back end from the console output and if successful the objects are created in the DB. The problem is that it seems if I am accessing this page fresh for the first time, it somehow reloads the page immediately after displaying the updated component. If I then submit the data again, this could be data to produce an error or create a new user then the flash message is displayed.

When this happens I am getting a message in the console, when the component loads and I dump the props, that states "props: changeReload". I have tried looking this up, but can't find any information.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import AuthService from '../auth/AuthService';
import axios from 'axios';

import {
  Row,
  Col,
  Container,
  InputGroup,
  Form,
  Button
} from "react-bootstrap";

export default class RegisterForm extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleChangeUsername = this.handleChangeUsername.bind(this);
    this.handleChangePassword = this.handleChangePassword.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeChk = this.handleChangeChk.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeEmail = this.handleChangeEmail.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.state = {messages: []};
    this.Auth = new AuthService();
  }

  handleChangeUsername(event) {
    this.setState({username: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangePassword(event) {
    this.setState({password: event.target.value });
  }

  handleChangeChk(event) {
    this.setState({chk: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeEmail(event) {
    this.setState({email: event.target.value });
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    return axios.post(localStorage.getItem('base_url')+'/user/register/', {
      username: this.state.username, pass: this.state.password,
      chk: this.state.chk, email: this.state.email
    }).then(res => {
        console.log("This is the data");
        console.log(res["data"]);
        if (res["data"].success) {
          this.props.setFlash("true",res["data"].messages,"info");
        } else {
          this.props.setFlash("true",res["data"].messages,"error");
        }
        this.setState({messages: res["data"].messages});
        this.setState({success: res["data"].success});
    })

  }

  componentDidMount(){
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row><Col><h3>Register</h3></Col></Row>
        <Row><Col><p>Complete the form below.</p></Col></Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>
            <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Username:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="text"  value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChangeUsername} />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Password:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChangePassword} />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Confirm Password:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="password" value={this.state.chk} onChange={this.handleChangeChk} />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group>
                <Form.Label>Email Address:</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control type="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={this.handleChangeEmail} />
              </Form.Group>

              <Button variant="primary" type="submit" value="Submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Row>
          <Col>{this.state.success ? <p>Registration Successful</p> : <p></p> }</Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}
```

Sorry for the poor explanation, it is hard for me to explain this well. I hope someone is able to recognise what this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form is submitting to the default URL, which is your current URL, that's why page is reloading.

Add this to the top of `handleSubmit` to avoid it:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  // ...
}
```